# All my functions have error C2084: function 'function' already has a body

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I've seen similar problems with overloading functions and this error elsewhere on the site, however this is happening to ALL of my functions, I've no idea what is happening or how to solve it.

I'm not sure if it is just that I've made a basic syntax error which has gone horribly wrong or something more sinister. If anyone has any ideas please help.

Oh and I apologise for the poor formatting of this question, it's the first question I've asked.

> error C2084: function 'Node::Node(Board *,int)' already has a body
>
> node.h(16) : see previous definition of '{ctor}'

Node.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Board.h"

class Node

{

private:

Board* nodeBoard;

int currentPlayer;

int value;  

Node** childrenNodes;
    
public:

//----some constructors----

Node(Board* board, int player)  {};

Node(Board* board)  {};

~Node(){};  

//----other functions----

Node generateChildren(int playerX, int playerY, Board* board)   {}

// other functions exist in the same format

};
```

Node.cpp

```
#pragma once

#include "Node.h"

Node::Node(Board* board, int player)
{

nodeBoard = board;

currentPlayer = player;

childrenNodes = NULL;

}

Node::Node(Board* board)
{

nodeBoard = board;

}
Node::~Node(){};

Node Node::generateChildren(int playerX, int playerY, Board* board)

{

//this fills the nodes based on if the squares next to the player are moveable 

}
```

P.s. Board is another class that i've made, it has the same problem as Node.

Comment: Although this is not the problem you are having you should not use pragma once in C++ source files only headers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Node(Board* board, int player) {};
```

sould be

```
Node(Board* board, int player);
```

in the class definition. The `{}` is an empty implementation, which renders the other definition illegal.

Same for the other constructors and methods. Alternitively, you can keep the implementations inline, in the class definition, but you then have to remove them from the implementation file.

Comment: That's worked. Thanks! Sorry to be a bother with such a simple thing.

Comment: @Tal: Note, that if the implementation is kept inline then every code file that includes the header must be recompiled if you change something in the implementation. This can cause very long unneccessary compile times which is why the definition and implementation are usually kept seperate.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the empty braces from your .h file - they don't belong there.